# WCF проблемы с ContractDescription

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf

Добрый день, у меня возникла необходимость построить serviceendpoint в сервисе исключительно программным методом без использования app.config и я наткнулся на не преодолимую проблему с ContractDescription, точнее

При конфигурирование ее сжато

```
ValueConfigurationService.WCFServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WCFService), new BasicHttpsBinding(), new Uri("http://localhost:8745/"));
```

все работает.
А вот такой конфигурации(расширенной) нет

```
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("WorkStation1.IWCFService"));
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Name = "MainEndpointRequesting";
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri(ValueConfigurationService.AddressMainEndpoint));
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Binding = ValueConfigurationService.ConfigurationBinding;
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Contract.Name = "AAAAAAAAAAAA";
        //ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(WorkStation1.IWCFService), typeof(WorkStation1.WCFService)); 
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.Contract.SessionMode = System.ServiceModel.SessionMode.Allowed;
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting.EndpointBehaviors.Add(ConfigurationBehavior);
```

пишет что проблема с контрактами

> System.ArgumentNullException: Значение не может быть неопределенным.
>   Имя параметра: key

Вопросс: как добавить тип контракта и тип службы в эту точку.

Answer (score 1):

да..........

```
        ContractDescription MainContract = ValueConfigurationService.WCFServiceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].Contract;
        MainContract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
        MainContract.SessionMode = System.ServiceModel.SessionMode.Allowed;
        ValueConfigurationService.MainEndpointRequesting = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint(MainContract);
```